# Mysql if exist update else insert

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql

I Sql server i use this command to insert value and if the id already exist update the vale

```
string commandLine = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT clientid FROM Rating WHERE clientid = " + clientId + " AND userid = " + userid + ") " +
            "INSERT INTO Rating VALUES(@clientId,@userid,@rating) " +
            "ELSE " +
            "UPDATE Rating SET rating=@rating WHERE clientid = " + clientId + " AND userid = " + userid + ";";
```

And i now move to `MySQL` and this command won't work. there is any thing same in MySQL?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does it give you an error?  Also, your code looks a bit confused.  You appear to be switching between concatenating values into your sql(bad!!!), and using parameters (good!!!).  It might make things a bit easier if you straighten that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) provides an easier syntax in MySQL and also gives you feedback as to what was happening via the affected-rows API call. Few people realise in my experience how handy it can come in your program logic to know that:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
> the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and
> 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

Comment: And if i don't have promary key?

Comment: Then add one. You should have one. Try learning about indexing in MySQL because it makes a big difference if you use them properly. This is a good [place](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) to start

Answer (score 2):

If you have unique constraint or primary key on  clientid, userid you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO Rating VALUES(@clientId,@userid,@rating)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE Rating SET rating=@rating
```